# global name '_tt_modules' is not defined

Tags: tornado

Using `tornado==4.1`

This is the app:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(templates.load("index.html").generate())

class NavModule(tornado.web.UIModule):
    def render(self):
        return self.render_string('modules/navigation.html')

class FooterModule(tornado.web.UIModule): 
    def render(self):
        return self.render_string('modules/footer.html')

application = tornado.web.Application(
        tornadio2.TornadioRouter(SocketConnection).apply_routes(routes),
        handlers=[(r'/', MainHandler)],
        ui_modules={'Footer': FooterModule,
        'NavigationModule': NavModule})
```

And part of the template page:

```
<ul>
{% block right-nav %}           
    <li>                
        {% module GlitchNavigationModule() %}       
    </li>                   
</ul>   
</section>      
{% end %}   
</div>  
    {% block footer %}      
<div class="container">         
    {% module Footer() %}   
</div>      
    {% end %}
```

For module `Footer` it works as expected, but for `NavigationModule` the error:

```
NameError: global name '_tt_modules' is not defined
```

I can do this instead:

```
{% include 'modules/navigation.html' %}
```

And even, [apparently](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/880) assign variables:

```
{% set some_variable = "text2" %}
```

But can anyone see or explain why only one of the modules actually works as expected?

Comment: Hmmm. In the template.py file it says ``UIModules`` are a feature of the `tornado.web.RequestHandler`
class (and specifically its ``render`` method) and will not work
when the template system is used on its own in other contexts. And I'm often using BaseHandler, which is a subclass of `tornado.web.RequestHandler`. Is it being used on it's own in other contexts if the template is being rendered by a Subclass of RequestHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `UIModules` you must use the `RequestHandler.render` method. This means passing `template_path` or `template_loader` to the `Application` constructor (instead of creating a global template loader as you seem to have done here), and using `self.render('index.html')` instead of `self.write(templates.load('index.html').generate())`

Comment: I see! Could you possibly add or point to an example, which includes sending variables to the template?

Comment: Any keyword arguments to `RequestHandler.render` will be passed to the template (same as keyword arguments to `Template.generate`). [Example](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/24aa16e881094e2233cd0bbfb59fb475d75673e2/demos/blog/blog.py#L109)